# Why are uibmodals only draggable on second call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I placed .draggable() on my modals but they only work on the second calls.
The modals are called from a service file.

Service file:

```
function callWarningModalService(data) {
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: vm.constants.WARNING,
    controller: vm.constants.WARNING_CONTROLLER,
    backdrop: vm.BACKDROP,
    resolve: {
       params: function () {
          return data;
        }
    }
  });

  $timeout(function () {
    $(".modal-content").draggable({ handle: ".modal-header" });
  }, 10);

  return modalInstance;
}
```

Inside callWarning() calling the modalService in Controller file:

```
modalService.callWarningModalService(vm.params).result.then(function (data) {
   if (data !== vm.constants.CANCEL) {
      vm.isDocumentAction = data;
      }
});
```

So yeah as a test, I moved a modal call from the service to the controller file and but same results were shown.

Inside callWarning() in Controller file

```
modal.message = vm.constants.WARNING_MESSAGE;
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: true,
  templateUrl: vm.constants.WARNING,
  controller: vm.constants.WARNING_CONTROLLER,
  backdrop: vm.BACKDROP,
  resolve: {
     params: function () {
        return modal;
      }
  }
});

$timeout(function () {
  $(".modal-content").draggable({ handle: ".modal-header" });
}, 10);

modalInstance.result.then(function () { });
```

I tried to debug it on chrome dev tools and it calls jquery-ui-draggable on first and the succeeding modal calls with the exact same patterns.

Is there a way so that the modals will already be draggable on the first call?
Why do you think it won't work on the first call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `draggable()` is not functioning properly is because you called the `draggable()` function after you executed the `$uibModal.open()`. The draggable should be executed inside your modal controller.

First, you can remove the argument on your `draggable()` function like this.

```
$timeout(function () {
  $(".modal-content").draggable();
}, 10);
```

According to [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_draggable.htm):

> The draggable (options) method declares that an HTML element can be moved in the HTML page. The options parameter is an object that specifies the behavior of the elements involved.

Second, you must transfer the `$timeout` function inside the `WARNING_CONTROLLER.js` and remove it from your `callWarning()` function. Your `callWarning()` function should look like this

```
function callWarning()
{
     modal.message = vm.constants.WARNING_MESSAGE;
     var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
         animation: true,
         templateUrl: vm.constants.WARNING,
         controller: vm.constants.WARNING_CONTROLLER,
         backdrop: vm.BACKDROP,
         resolve: {
             params: function () {
                 return modal;
             }
         }
     });

     modalInstance.result.then(function () { });
}
```